# Oracle Apex. Подключение папки Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Пытаюсь установить Oracle Apex, запустив скрипты.
Завёл пользователя, залогинился. Теперь пытаюсь подключить папку apex. Скопировал адрес, через cd показал - всё ок. Получаю ошибку:

```
sqlplus sys/{passwd}@localhost/xepdb1 as sysdba @apexins sysaux sysaux temp /i/
[...]
. XDB
. pass - is valid
. PL/SQL Web Toolkit
. pass - version 11.2.0.0.1
. Tablespaces
. pass - found sysaux
. pass - found sysaux
. pass - found temp
. PHASES (1,2,3)...
. FAIL - Precondition for Phase 1 failed: APEX_200100 already exists
.
. 2 errors occurred 
‘declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: Prerequisite checks failed; unable to proceed with APEX installation
ORA-06512: at line 288

Disconnected from Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

C:\app\ASTER\apex>
```

Читал, что можно как-то удалить полностью Oracle Apex с помощью `@apxremov.sql`. Но при попытке получаю это:

```
C:\Users\ASTER> sqlplus / as sysdba;

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Sep 29 10:35:32 2021
Version 18.4.8.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle. All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 18.4.0.0.0

SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> @apxremov.sql
SP2-0318: unable to open file “apxremov.sql"
```

Что я делаю не так? Куда и как правильно вписывать `@apxremov.sql`?

---

UPD: Сейчас пытаюсь начать обучение SQL, иду по "инструкции" от авторов курса. При попытке установки Apex получаю такую вот ошибку (см. выше). Обратился к ним с вопросом, как быть - посоветовали полностью переустановить Apex, предварительно запустив `@apxremov.sql`, "ткнули" [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779964/error-while-installing-oracle-apex). Пытаюсь, но видимо что-то делаю неправильно.

Comment: Так с чем же у вас конкретно затруднения возникли? Установить  Apex или удалить его?

Answer (score 4):

Для удаления ранее установленой среды разработки Apex проделайте следующие шаги.

Перейдите в каталог, из которого была ранее устанвлена Apex, под Windows это, например:

```
C:\> cd /d d:\install\apex
```

Далее, вызовете SQL*Plus с учётной записью, с которой была установлена БД. После успешной авторизации, перейдите в подключаемую БД, где был установлена Apex (в вопросе - xepdb1):

```
D:\install\apex> sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL> alter session set container=xepdb1;

Session altered.
```

Выполните скрипт для удаления Apex:

```
SQL> @ apxremov 

...Removing Application Express

[... сообщения о ходе выполнения ...]

...Application Express Removed

********************************************************************
** You must exit this SQL*Plus session before running apexins.sql **
********************************************************************
```