# Как установить среду разработки APEX?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Участник [@Shelest.4VS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1335125) спрашивал, как полностью удалить Apex после неуспешной установки.

А как установить среду разработки APEX и при этом избежать ошибок?

Читая официальную [документацию по установке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1335125), некоторые моменты не совсем понятны. Особенно, как подготовить БД для установки. Например, стоит ли устанавливать в корневую БД (CDB), или устанавливать в новую или уже имеющуся подключаемую БД. Или, нужно ли создавать отдельное табличное пространство.

Хочется с наименьшими позаниями в администрировании БД оптимально подготовить ее к установке, провести установку, и в итоге избежать ошибок при установке. Ведь интересно же без особых временных затрат установить среду APEX, попробовать ее или начать обучение с ней.

Answer (score 6):

На сегодня последняя версия 21.01. В основу положена [оф. документация по установке](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.1/htmig/downloading-installing-apex.html#GUID-B5A5B38D-586C-488A-AE27-A168FAA28FEE).

Отличия при установки на Nix* или Win в указании путей и некоторых команд в командной строке, например: `/app/apex` = `C:\app\apex`.

1. Скачайте [последнюю версию с оф.сайта](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/apex-downloads.html) в любой каталог. На выбор, или среда только с англ. языком, или мультиязычная.
2. Перейдите в ранее выбраный каталог и распакуйте архив любой программой архиватором. Затем перейдите в только что созданный каталог apex:

   ```
   cd /app/
   unzip -q apex_21.1.zip
   cd apex
   ```
3. Выполните подключение как привилигированый пользователь `SYS`:

   ```
   # если еще не установлены; в Win команда SET   
   export ORACLE_SID=oracl 
   export ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/home

   sqlplus -l / as sysdba
   ```
4. Рекомендуемый путь - создать новую подключаемую БД и отдельноое табличное пространство:

   ```
   create pluggable database pdb2 admin user pdbadmin identified by pdb$admin 
       file_name_convert = ('pdbseed', 'pdb2');

   alter pluggable database pdb2 open;
   alter pluggable database pdb2 save state;
   alter session set container=pdb2;
   create tablespace apex datafile '/dbfiles/cdb193/pdb2/apex01.dbf' 
       size 100m autoextend on next 1m;
   ```
5. Для установки полной среды разработки выполните скрипт:

   ```
   -- @apexins.sql tablespace_apex tablespace_files tablespace_temp images

   @ apexins.sql apex apex temp /i/
   ...set_appun.sql
   [много диагностических сообщений, продолж. ~20 мин.]
   ```

   Будет создан лог установки, например: install2021-10-09_17-07-04.log
6. Изменните ппароль администратора APEX запуском скрипта:

   ```
   @ apxchpwd.sql
   Enter the administrator's username [ADMIN]
   User "ADMIN" does not yet exist and will be created.
   Enter ADMIN's email [ADMIN]
   Enter ADMIN's password []
   Created instance administrator ADMIN.
   ```
7. Измените пароль для общего пользователя APEX:

   ```
   alter user apex_public_user identified by apex account unlock;
   ```
8. Конфигурируйте RESTful службы для APEX запуском скрипта:

   ```
   @ apex_rest_config.sql
   Enter a password for the APEX_LISTENER user              []
   Enter a password for the APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER user              []
   ...set_appun.sql
   ...setting session environment
   ...create APEX_LISTENER and APEX_REST_PUBLIC_USER users
   ```

На этом установка APEX завершена. Проверить установку можно, либо коротким запросом, либо запустив скрипт проверки:

```
select version, status 
from dba_registry where comp_id='APEX';

VERSION                        STATUS     
------------------------------ -----------
21.1.0                         VALID      

@ ./utilities/support/apex_verify.sql
```

Последний создаст в текущем каталоге файл apex_verify_out.html, который можно открыть в любом HTML просмотрщике и получить подробнейшую информацию о установленном APEX.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант - развёртываниe Oracle APEX в Docker-контейнере. Очень удобно для разработчиков: нужно просто установить Docker и запустить контейнер.

Одна проблема: не существует официальных контейнеров от Oracle со сборками APEX. По крайней мере, я таких не нашёл на hub.docker.com.

Из самого удобного находил [такую сборку](https://github.com/Dani3lSun/docker-db-apex-dev).

Плюс:

- в сборке можно удобно кофигурировать разные комбинации версий БД, Апекса и других подсистем.

Минус:

- последняя версия в сборке (по крайней мере пока) только для версии 20.2, и не понятно, будет ли автор обновлять сборку.