# Как наиболе просто установить и сконфигурировать ORDS для работы с APEX?

Tags: sql, oracle, веб-сервер, oracle-apex

В [этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1336665/217579) было рассмотерено, как установить среду разработки APEX.

APEX это только структуры и объекты БД, такие как схемы, таблицы, пакеты итд. Для работы с APEX необходим Web Listener (прослушиватель). Начиная [с версии 20.2 больше не поддерживаются](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/20.2/htmig/changes-in-this-release.html#GUID-0D0A4621-4D96-4776-AC62-E9310B3C6032) прослушиватели Embedded PL/SQL Gateway и Oracle HTTP Server (mod_plsql), есть только возможность использовать ORDS (Oracle REST Data Services).

ORDS это написаный на Java-EE Web сервер, который устанавливается на сервер приложений - WebLogic или Apache Tomcat.

Как наиболе просто установить и сконфигурировать ORDS для работы с APEX?

Преследуемая цель - без особых временных затрат и познаний в области администрировании БД - установить, провести конфигурцию, и в итоге, начать работу со средой разработки APEX.

Answer (score 3):

На сегодня последняя версия 21.3. В основу положена [оф. документация по установке и конфигурации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.3/aelig/installing-REST-data-services.html#GUID-B6661F35-3EE3-4CB3-9379-40D0B8E24635).

Предварительнае замечания:

- Потребуется Java 8 или более поздние версии.
- Развертывание ORDS с использованием Oracle WebLogic Server или Apache Tomcat имеет смысл в продуктивной среде, для теста или обучения достаточно автономномного режима (*standalone mode*).
- ORDS это полностью самостоятельный программный продукт, который не входит в состав поставки APEX.
- Так как, предполлогаемое использование: тест или обучение, то аспекты безопасности: HTTPS, сертификаты и тп, ниже не рассматриваются.

1. Скачайте [последнюю версию с оф.сайта](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.3/aelig&id=OTN_download) в любой каталог.
2. Перейдите в ранее выбраный каталог и распакуйте архив любой программой архиватором. Затем перейдите в каталог, куда произошла распаковка. Здесь находится Java архив ords.war. С опцией help можно ознакомится с раазличными режимами работы ORDS:

   ```
   cd /app/install 
   unzip -q ords-21.3.0.266.1100.zip -d /app/ords

   cd /app/ords

   java -jar ords.war help
   ```
3. Создайте каталог для файлов конфигурации:

   ```
   mkdir conf
   java -jar ords.war configdir $PWD/conf
   ```
4. Создайте табличное пространство для ORDS, путь длля него определите простым запросом:

   ```
   $ sqlplus sys/'pass'@localhost/pdb2 as sysdba

   SQL> select regexp_substr (file_name, '^.*/') path 
        from dba_data_files where rownum=1;

        /dbfiles/orcl/pdb2/

   SQL> create tablespace ords datafile '/dbfiles/orcl/pdb2/ords01.dbf' size 100m autoextend on next 1m;
   ```
5. Для простой установки без ввода в командной строке, следует отредактировать файл параметров конфигурации params/ords_params.properties. Полное описание параметроов [в этой подглаве](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.3/aelig/installing-REST-data-services.html#GUID-EB2BD2FA-48C2-4786-BDA3-C35A20555F40).
   Пример его содержимого:

   ```
   db.hostname=localhost
   db.port=1521
   db.servicename=pdb2
   db.username=APEX_PUBLIC_USER
   db.password=apex

   migrate.apex.rest=false
   rest.services.apex.add=true
   rest.services.ords.add=true
   schema.tablespace.default=ORDS
   schema.tablespace.temp=TEMP

   standalone.use.http=true
   standalone.http.port=8080
   standalone.static.images=/app/apex/images

   user.apex.listener.password=apex
   user.apex.restpublic.password=apex

   user.public.password=ords
   user.tablespace.default=ORDS
   user.tablespace.temp=TEMP
   sys.user=SYS
   sys.password=SysPassword

   restEnabledSql.active=true
   feature.sdw=true
   database.api.enabled=true
   plsql.gateway.add=true
   ```

   Не забудте после установки удалить из текста пароли!!!
6. Установка заключается в запуске Java архива (приведён пример вывода):

   ```
   $ java -jar ords.war
   Connecting to database user: SYS AS SYSDBA url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/pdb2

   Retrieving information.
   2021-10-16T13:50:18.891Z INFO        reloaded pools: []
   Installing Oracle REST Data Services version 21.3.0.r2661100
   ... Log file written to /vol/db/home/oracle/ords_install_core_2021-10-16_155019_00454.log
   ... Verified database prerequisites
   ... Created Oracle REST Data Services proxy user
   ... Created Oracle REST Data Services schema
   ... Granted privileges to Oracle REST Data Services
   ... Created Oracle REST Data Services database objects
   ... Log file written to /vol/db/home/oracle/ords_install_datamodel_2021-10-16_155102_00886.log
   ... Log file written to /vol/db/home/oracle/ords_install_apex_2021-10-16_155106_00855.log
   Completed installation for Oracle REST Data Services version 21.3.0.r2661100. Elapsed time: 00:00:51.581

   Enter 1 if you wish to start in standalone mode or 2 to exit [1]:2
   ```

   В выводе указаны логи установки.
7. В случае ошибок, повторите установку только после удаления ORDS из БД и каталога конфигурации:

   ```
   java -jar ords.war uninstall simple

   rm -r conf/
   ```

На этом установка ORDS завершена.

Стартовать ORDS в автономномном режиме можно, запустив скрипт в терминале:

```
$ mkdir logs

$ nohup java -jar ords.war standalone 2>&1 >logs/ords.log_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S) &
```

Для работа с APEX наберите в адресной строке HTML просмотрщика:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

В открывшемся окне наберите рабочее пространство internal и данные уч.записи администратора APEX, созданные [в пункте 6 при установке APEX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1336665/217579):

[image]